# Objective-C: most efficient way to map from number to according NSRange in NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, performance, algorithm

I've got a lot of objects with according ranges:

```
Object1 => 0 - 23
Object2 => 24 - 84
Object3 => 85 - 103
...
```

Those ranges vary, now I'm looking for the most efficient way in Objective-C to say "okay, I've got the number 56; which object has the according range? Ah, yes: it's Object2".

Any ideas? Binary search? Something else?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Save end points of ranges and use binary search =)

Comment: A `NSArray` using `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` would also work (but be less efficient).  Once you filter the array you can get the index of the `NSRange` object and use that index to get your custom objects from another `NSArray` associated with that range.  See [Predicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789).

Comment: I'm looking for the most performant way, so filtering is no option, I'm afraid. Seems like I'm ending up with binary search, I assume?

Comment: Do the ranges always follow each other with no gaps?  Never (3,6),(9,20) for example?

Comment: yes, there are no gaps! your example: 0-2, 3-6, 7-8, 9-20, 21-...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks pretty much like finding the position of a specified value in a sorted list of the different points of your segment, in your case you can take for example : [-0.5,23.5,84.5,103.5] it's the list of the midpoint between start and end of each segment.

if position of you specified value is 1 => object 1

if it's 2 => object2

if it's 3 => object 3

For 56 you would get 2 => object 2

hope it helps

---

**Edit :**

For an array A of size N, the pseudo code for this modified binary search would be.

```
  min := 0; //my array start at index 0
  max := N-1; 
  repeat
    mid := (min+max) div 2;
    if x > A[mid] then
      min := mid + 1;
    else
      max := mid - 1;
  until (A[mid+1] > x >A[mid]) or (min > max);
  return mid+1
```

I modified the condition until (cf [wikipedia article on binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Implementations)) to fit the constraint of the problem. I am modifying the mid until x is between 2 elements and I return mid+1

Comment: sounds interesting... but how can I manage that 56 delivers 2? Again I'm at binary search, I assume?

Comment: @swalkner I tried to write a pseudo code for the binary search, I edited my post, the idea of the search is to find where I can insert X in A.(A is sorted), sorry I don't know enough objective C to translate the code in objective C